# Pipreqs installation

Tags: python, web-applications, streamlit, requirements.txt

I am having difficulty generating the requirements.txt file. It says directory not found on I change the directory to file location. I have created my webapp using streamlit library.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.2251]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\lucy22>cd firstprog
The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\Users\lucy22>cd C:\Users\lucy22\PycharmProjects\firstprog\error404.py
The directory name is invalid.

C:\Users\lucy22>pip3 install pipreqs
Requirement already satisfied: pipreqs in c:\users\lucy22\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (0.4.11)
Requirement already satisfied: docopt in c:\users\lucy22\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pipreqs) (0.6.2)
Requirement already satisfied: yarg in c:\users\lucy22\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pipreqs) (0.1.9)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\lucy22\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from yarg->pipreqs) (2.26.0)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in c:\users\lucy22\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from requests->yarg->pipreqs) (3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer~=2.0.0 in c:\users\lucy22\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from requests->yarg->pipreqs) (2.0.6)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\lucy22\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from requests->yarg->pipreqs) (2021.10.8)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\lucy22\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from requests->yarg->pipreqs) (1.26.7)
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.1.3; however, version 22.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'c:\users\lucy22\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.


C:\Users\lucy22>cd C:\Users\lucy22\PycharmProjects\firstprog\error404.py
The directory name is invalid.
```

Answer (score 0):

**To generate requirements.txt**

```py
pipreqs --encoding=utf8 C:\\Users\\lucy22\\PycharmProjects\\firstprog
```

**Why you got that error:**
You got that error message because you are trying to open `error404.py` file with a `cd` command, the `cd` command is used for navigating through `directories` and `error404.py` is a file not a directory.

**To navigate or change directory:**
Your working directory is `C:\Users\lucy22`. So there is no need to include that in you command.

You should rather write the below command and that will take you to the `firstprog` directory where your `error404.py` file is located.:

```
cd PycharmProjects\firstprog
```

**To open a file:**
If you are looking to open `error404.py` file, you should use the `open` command.
***Example:***

```py
open PycharmProjects\firstprog\error404.py
```